# Is there a workaround to having a link with fixed height and centered on the container?

Tags: html, css

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/U6MYR/) :

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="link" href="http://www.website.com">My Link</a>
</div>

.container
{
    width:400px; 
    text-align:center;
}

.link
{
    background-color:red;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

I don't want to use inline block (because IE7 doesnt support it).
And I don't want to use margin/padding left to my div container to center it, setting block to the link.

Is there any way to make a fixed height for this kind of situation? Line-height doesnt get background-color, and my font-size must be 14px.

Comment: I'm not sure you've actually asked a question here?  What is it you want to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline-block` support with the `*` hack. write like this:

```
.link
{
    background-color:red;
    font-size:14px;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;/* For IE7*/
   *zoom:1;/* For IE7*/
   vertical-align:top;

}
```

Comment: Wow...seems to works! Also without * and display:inline;? Seems that only zoom:1 resolve this problem :O Or am I wrong?

Comment: your write because Anchor default value is inline.

Comment: ah, so this workaround rocks on block native elements! Thank you :) Very nice trick